# "a passing similarity"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "a passing similarity" mean, and what does "passing" mean?

For example,

> The current statistics on child abuse are terrifying in their implications, and the abuse cuts across every socioeconomic and racial group. Child abuse bears more than a passing similarity to radiation poisoning, because it silently works its effects on subsequent generations, but through the subtle but potent effect of disrupted attachment relationships and the epigenetic changes that have been discovered since this book was first published.

(from *Creating Sanctuary*, 2nd edition
 By Sandra L Bloom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A passing similarity* means **a slight similarity**. From your context,

> *Child abuse **bears more than a passing similarity to** radiation poisoning, ...*

The *"bears more than a passing similarity to"* means that child abuse does not have just a little similarity to radiation poisoning. In other words, child abuse is actually quite like radiation poisoning.

Here is a definition of *passing* by [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/passing),

> **passing**
>   <sup>adjective [only before noun]</sup>
>   3. slight
>       *She bore a passing resemblance to the missing woman.*

Answer (score 1):

"Pass" in this context means something like "to just get by".

So a passing similarity is a similarity that is just close enough that you really call it a similarity.  You might say "Taco Bell passes for Mexican food around here" which means that you think that it's not a good example of Mexican food, but lots of people don't know know any better.

Also related, "passing" is what it was called when a non-white person lives their life as if they were really white, which includes leaving all their old friends and family behind.